# error when press print order in crystal report runtime vs 12

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

make exe program in c# with crystal report v12

when press print order in crystal report this error view

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

befor crystal report version is 2005 and every thinks work fine . but when upgrade to vs 12 some times allow me to print .and athor time this error show. i solve this problem by reinstall crystalreport runtime in client machine. but i need best solution for this problem .

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the software and more importantly in this case the drivers.

You could report the problem to the 3rd party reporting vendor in hope they can identify the problem and fix it.

Otherwise it's good you've found a fix.

Comment: vendor sap crystal report comany using .net 2012 and install sap crystal report for .net and runtime in client pc

Comment: Yeah take it up with their tech support or refer your clients to their tech support